# My C# script isn't doing anything in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have just started game development in unity. In the tutorial that I'm following, it tells me to attach my script to my ball (player), which is supposed to make it move. When I run the program though, nothing happens, and when I make it write in console to see if it runs, it doesn't write anything, which makes me think that either something is wrong with my code, or that VS Code doesn't work with unity. Here's my code in case you want it.

```
using System.Collection;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AddConstantVelocity : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        Console.Writeline("Moving");
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it attached? Do you get any errors in the console?  Does the thing it’s attached to have a rigid body? Is the thing it’s attached to a visible object

Comment: In general in Unity you want to use `Debug.Log` not `Console.WriteLine`

Answer (score 2):

1. If you want to see log in Unity console you should use `Debug.Log("smth");`
2. You don't need getting access to the Rigidbody component in Update (many times per frame), cache it once in `Start()`
3. Make sure that you added your script to the GameObject you wanted to move (check Unity debug logs)

   ```
   private Rigidbody rb;

   private void Start()
   {
       rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
   }

   private void Update()
   {
       Debug.Log("Moving");
       rb.velocity = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
   }
   ```